# Understanding frequency of a signal

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, frequency

I'm trying to understand how can one transmit different signals on a same copper wire using different frequencies. How does the electrons actually interact with the frequency? And how does the frequency relates to the speed of a connection?

Comment: This should help : http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P5337fa11/notes/ch06/chapter6.pdf...

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a Fourier series or a Fourier transform?

Comment: @DanielSank no, for the sake of answering in a very understandable way, assume i know no more than someone who was accepted into university.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop two pebbles into a lake, the waves can overlap, but the waves are still distinct. In a similar manner, if you have two different frequencies (two separate waves with different frequencies) sent into the wire, although they may overlap they still remain distinct. For an AC wave, the electrons literally just move back and forth in the conduction band. The faster they move back and forth, the faster you can transmit data along them. Think of it in terms of morse code. The faster you get the dots and dashes, the faster you get the words, the higher the data transfer. As daaxix's PDF showed, its actually quite a bit more complicated, but that  is the basic gist of it.